# Expected type 'object'. Found 'array'

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentando realizar un validador de login, pero me sale error en un dato de password_verify y nose por q me sucede

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ValidadorLogin (*Aqui es donde se detecta el error indicado en un comentario*):

```
public function __construct($email, $clave, $conexion)
{
    $this -> error = "";
    if (!$this -> variable_iniciada($email) || !$this -> variable_iniciada($clave)){
        $this -> usuario = null;
        $this -> error = "Debes introducir tu email y tu contraseña";
    } else {
        $this -> usuario = RepositorioUsuario::obtener_usuario_por_email($conexion, $email);
        
        //comprobamos si la contaseña no es correcta(descifrandola) 
        //la contraseña es lo que me da fallo(password_verify)
            if(is_null($this -> usuario) || !password_verify($clave, $this -> usuario -> obtener_password())){
           
            $this -> error = "Datos incorrectos";
        }
    }
}
```

RepositorioUsuario:

```
public static function obtener_usuario_por_email($conexion, $email){
        $usuario = null;

        if(isset($conexion)/*Conexion existe*/){
            try{
                include_once "Usuario.inc.php";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email";
                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
                $sentencia -> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sentencia -> execute();
                $sentencia->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Usuario');
                $usuario=array();

                while ($row = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $usuario[]=$row;
                }
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                print 'ERROR'.$ex -> getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $usuario;
    }
```

Archivo usuario.inc(Aqui tengo la clase de obtener_password):

```
class Usuario {
        private $dni;
        private $nombre;
        private $email;
        private $password;
        private $fecha_registro;
        private $administrador;

        public function __construct($dni, $nombre, $email, $password, $fecha_registro, $administrador){
            //El atributo de la clase es el mismo al q pasamos al constructor
            $this -> dni = $dni;
            $this -> nombre = $nombre;
            $this -> email = $email;
            $this -> password = $password;
            $this -> fecha_registro = $fecha_registro;
            $this -> administrador = $administrador;
        }

       public function obtener_password(){
            return $this -> password;
        }
```

Adjunto el error, la linea 23 es la imagen superior.:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function obtener_password() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\ValidadorLogin.inc.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\clientes\login_c.php(8): ValidadorLogin->__construct('ismaelmontoyaco...', '1234', Object(PDO)) #1 {main} thrown

Comment: Por un lado defines el usuario como array aquí:  `$usuario=array();` y por el otro intentas sacarle una propiedad de objeto a ese array aquí: `$this -> usuario -> obtener_password()`, y de ahi el error que tienes.

Comment: Lo he editado asi, pero me sigue saliendo el error de que no puedo llamar a obtener_password y no entiendo por que.
$allUsers=array();
while ($row = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $allUsers[]=$row;
                }
$usuario = $allUsers[0];

Comment: Lo que estas devolviendo no es objeto esta vez, sino de nuevo un array, en este caso asociativo, donde seguramente puedes sacar la pasword sin tener que usar la función `obtener_password` sino simplemente escribiendo `$this->usuario['password']`

Comment: Perfecto, nose controlar del todo bien los $this, ya me funciona a ver como sigue, Gracias.

Comment: ¿Es un ejercicio quizás?  Lo digo porque si te obligan a usar una clase para el usuario y esa función obtener_password, entonces lo que deberias hacer es crear la instancia del objeto en obtener_usuario_por_email() mediante un `$usuario = new Usuario ($dni, $nombre, $email, $password, $fecha_registro, $administrador);`

Comment: Es una pagina web que estoy creando para un proyecto final a base de tutoriales de youtube, por eso mi ignorancia en cuanto a conocimiento de php, voy a fallo y error y aprendiendo ya que lo mucho que me han enseñado de php es un while y un for.

Comment: Bueno, entonces no te hace falta usar el objeto Usuario, con lo que ya te he dicho antes puedes continuar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138627/discussion-between-ismael-montoya-and-masterguru).